# URL for review page - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, url, magento-1.9

While I click on Product Review page, my url gets change. 
e.g.
Product URL: https://beyondgallery.com/dark-blue-kurta.html
Review URL: https://beyondgallery.com/review/product/list/id/5047/category/274/#review-form

Need to get the URL like: dark-blue-kurta-reivew

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is by creating and using custom router.

Refer this reference blog for creating the custom router in Magento: http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-router-in-magento/

In `match` function you can add the condition like if found `-review` in request path info then add your logic.

And we can change the review list link to https://beyondgallery.com/dark-blue-kurta-reivew by rewrite `getReviewsUrl` function of `Mage_Review_Block_Helper` helper.

Hope it helps!